# Confusion in integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

The following integral when solved by integration by parts comes out to be zero.

$$\int^{10}_{0}f(x,y)\dfrac{d^{2}[g(x,y)]}{dxdy}dx$$
$$=\left[ \int f(x,y)\dfrac{d^{2}[g(x,y)]}{dxdy}dx \right]^{10}_{0}$$
$$=\left[ f(x,y)\dfrac{d[g(x,y)]}{dy}-\int\dfrac{d[f(x,y)]}{dx}\dfrac{d[g(x,y)]}{dy}dx \right]^{10}_{0}$$
{integration by parts}
$$=\left[ f(x,y)\dfrac{d[g(x,y)]}{dy}-\dfrac{d[g(x,y)]}{dy} \int\dfrac{d[f(x,y)]}{dx}dx \right]^{10}_{0}$$
{since $\dfrac{d[g(x,y)]}{dy}$ is a function of $y$ and can be taken outside integration w.r.t. $x$}
$$=\left[ f(x,y)\dfrac{d[g(x,y)]}{dy}-\dfrac{d[g(x,y)]}{dy} f(x,y) \right]^{10}_{0}=0$$

This integral is coming out to be zero for any $f(x,y)$ or $g(x,y)$ at any $y$

**CHECKING**

Let $f(x,y)=xy$ and $g(x,y)=x^{2}y$
$$\dfrac{d^{2}[g(x,y)]}{dxdy}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[ \dfrac{d(x^{2}y)}{dy}   \right]=\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x$$

$$\int^{10}_{0}f(x,y)\dfrac{d^{2}[g(x,y)]}{dxdy}dx=\int^{10}_{0}(xy.2x) dx=2y\int^{10}_{0}x^{2} dx=2y\left[  \dfrac{x^{3}}{3}  \right]^{10}_{0}$$
$$=2y\left[  \dfrac{1000}{3}-\dfrac{0}{3}  \right]=\dfrac{2000}{3}y$$

Now this is not coming out to be zero at any $y$. Why is this contradiction happening? Am I somewhere wrong while doing integration by parts?

Comment: LaTeX tip: use \partial for partial derivatives instead of d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y)
$$
is not a function only of $y$. It also dependes on $x$.